# Appending Function Variables

Tags: function, variables

I am creating a RPG game in which I use a function for health and potions. After every enemy encounter the player looses a random amount of health. If the the hero has a potions left they gain the given health. I'm trying to save the health and potion amount for when the next encounter occurs the health and potions are the same from the last encounter. How do i append or save the variables for the next round??? Here is the code i have for the function.

```
    import random
    health = 20
    potion = 5
    playerdamage = random.randint(0, 7)
    print("\nDuring the fight you took", playerdamage, "damage!")
    health -= playerdamage
    if potion > 0:
        print("You have a health potion to use!")
        health += 5
        potion -= 1
        print("You gained 5 health back and are now at",health,"health!")
        print("you have", potion, "health potion(s) left!")
    else:
        print("You have no health potions left!")
        print("You have", health, "health left\n")

    return health
```

Here is the Full code

```
def main():
    choice = None
    while choice != "0":
        print("\nThe time has come to choose your path!")
        print(
"""
0 - quit
1 - Start adventure!
"""
          )
        choice = input("Choice: ")
        if choice == "0":
            print("Good-bye")

        elif choice == "1":
            print("\n\nLets see what kind of hero you would like to be!")
            character_select()
        else:
            print("That is not an option")
    return

def character_select():
     choiceB = None
     while choiceB != "0":
         print("\nWho will you be?")
         print(
            """
0 - return
1 - Warrior
2 - Mage
""")
         choiceB = input("Choice: ")
         if choiceB == "0":
             print("Returning to main menu")

         elif choiceB == "1":
             print("\nYou have chosen the path of the mighty Warrior!")
             input("\nPress enter to start the adventure")
             adventure_start()

         elif choiceB == "2":
             print("\nYou will follow the path of the all powerful Mage!")
             input("\nPress enter to start the adventure")
             adventure_start()

         else:
             print("\nI'm sorry thats not an option")

def adventure_start():
    print("\n\nYou have been asked to venture into a rundown castle \nthat has been recently taken over by a band of highwaymen.")
    print("It has taken several hours to get to the castle.")
    print("As you aproach the castle you see several Highwayman standing outside")
    input("\nPress enter to start your attack!")
    encounter()
    playerhealth()
    input("\nPress enter to continue into the castle")
    print("\nAs you enter the courtyard you see there are 3 enterences!")
    choiceC = None
    while choiceC!= "0":
        print("You see three choices in your path!")
        print("As you look around you can head through the \n1:Tower,\n2:the stairs off the the left or \n3:continue through the Main Castle Door.")
        choiceC = input("Choice: \n\n")
        if choiceC == "1":
            tower()
        elif choiceC == "2":
            stairs()
        elif choiceC == "3":
            main_castledoor()
        else:
            print("That is not one of the options Hero. Please try one of the three paths before its too late!")
    return

def playerhealth():
    import random
    health = 20
    potion = 5
    playerdamage = random.randint(0, 7)
    print("\nDuring the fight you took", playerdamage, "damage!")
    health -= playerdamage
    if potion > 0:
        print("You have a health potion to use!")
        health += 5
        potion -= 1
        print("You gained 5 health back and are now at", health,"health!")
        print("you have", potion, "health potion(s) left!")
    else:
        print("You have no health potions left!")
        print("You have", health, "health left\n")
    return 


def encounter():
    import random
    highwayman = random.randint(2,4)
    print("\n\nthere are",highwayman ,"Highwayman")
    print("You attack the closest Highwayman\n")
    while highwayman > 0:
        highwaymanhealth = 5
        while highwaymanhealth >= 1:
            damage = random.randint(5,10)
            highwaymanhealth -= damage
            print("You hit the Highwayman and did", damage, "damage to them!")
            highwayman -= 1
            print("there are", highwayman, "left.")
    print("The Highwayman have been defeated!")
    return


def stairs():
    print("Something about the stairs\n draws you attention and you start heading toward them.")
    print("As you reach the top of the stairs you enter an empty hallway.")
    print("You hear voices coming from a behind a door at the end of the hall.")
    print("Slowly creeping towards the door you verify that the voices are coming from within.")
    print("Gently openning the door you find yourself at the top of a stair case within the Great Hall!")
    greathall()
    return 

def tower():
    print("You hear a noice coming from the tower and run to the door!")
    print("As you run into the tower you come face to face with another group of Highwayman!")
    encounter()
    playerhealth()
    greathall()
    return

def main_castledoor():
    print("As you enter the main enterence you come across another group of Highwayman!")
    encounter()
    playerhealth()
    print("")
    greathall()
    return

def greathall():
    input("\nPress enter to continue.\n\n")
    print("Upon entering the Great Hall you realize that you have just come face to face with the main force of the Highwayman and their leader!")
    print("")
    encounter()
    final_step()
    return

def final_step():
    print("You are victorious in defeating the Highwayman! As you look around you see a chest full of Gold and a strange orb.")
    print("While you collect the gold you are careful not to touch the orb and walk away. However, as you are about to leave you can't get it off your mind...")
    print("\n\n Slowly walking back to the chest you stare at the orb. Entranced by the swirling smoke within you find yourself reaching towards it.")
    print("As you are about to grab the orb you stop. Something doesn't feel right, but you grab the orb anyways.")
    print("Instantly you realize it was a mistake. Your body feels as if it was just jerked backwards and everything goes black.")
    print("\n\n\nThanks for playing!")
    print("You have reached the end")
    main()
    return




main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to consider here: how to organize the code, and how to organize the data.  To repeatedly "encounter enemies," use a subroutine (i.e. a def statement).  To store the data, you have two options: creating a player type, or storing data in global variables.  If you can guarantee that the game will involve only one player, using globals is easier, but less extensible.
To go the global route:

```
import random
health = 20
potion = 5

def encounterEnemy():
    playerdamage = random.randint(0, 7)
    print("\nDuring the fight you took", playerdamage, "damage!")
    health -= playerdamage
    if potion > 0:
        print("You have a health potion to use!")
        health += 5
        potion -= 1
        print("You gained 5 health back and are now at",health,"health!")
        print("you have", potion, "health potion(s) left!")
    else:
        print("You have no health potions left!")
        print("You have", health, "health left\n")
    return health
```

Then, each time you call `encounterEnemy`, the player's life total and potions will be adjusted accordingly.

To create a new data type:

```
import random
class Player:
    def __init__(health, potion):
        self.health = health
        self.potion = potion
    def encounterEnemy():
        playerdamage = random.randint(0, 7)
        print("\nDuring the fight you took", playerdamage, "damage!")
        self.health -= playerdamage
        if self.potion > 0:
            print("You have a health potion to use!")
            self.health += 5
            self.potion -= 1
            print("You gained 5 health back and are now at", self.health, "health!")
            print("you have", self.potion, "health potion(s) left!")
        else:
            print("You have no health potions left!")
            print("You have", self.health, "health left\n")
        return self.health

currPlayer = Player(20, 5)
currPlayer.encounterEnemy()
```

Creating a new data type is also useful because it lets you "bundle" all the data associated with the problem together.

Comment: I have other functions as well that work off each other. Where would the health and potion then go. The main function?

Comment: Neither worked for me. I edited the post and posted full code for program.